# Error when building after renaming "com.example"

Tags: android, gradle, build

Ok so when releasing an apk google play said that I need to use a different package name because "com.example" is restricted. After that i rename the package and suddenly gradle just stops building with the following errors in the "build folder".
[image of the errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/feHmF.png)

Comment: you probably need file/invalidate cache and restart. Make sure you click the highlighted "Invalidate and Restart" on the popup window.

Comment: already tried that

Comment: one more try, make sure you match your compileSdkVersion as well. It is probably out of sync with your support library / build tools . I believe you are mixing V26 and V28 or something related to these.

Comment: compileSkVersion is 26 and every support library is 26.1.0. I dont think that i am mixing them or a t least i cant find where.

Comment: you were actullay right it did the trick, thank you